# I need help understanding how to set warn and critical thresholds for Nagios

Tags: nagios

I need help understanding how to set warn and critical thresholds for Nagios.

I am currently using Nagios3 & NRPE & NSCLIENT.

I have created a custom powershell script to check for running processes on a Windows box using NSCLient++. Works well so far!

My issue is how do I set the threshold Metric.. I.e metric=time warn=10 crit=15

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Done a bit of thinking came across an NSClient++ VBS script which happened to specify ranges and dug about on the net for a while.

Solution was to code the range and thresholds within my (external script effectively making it a full blown plugin). Was previously under the impression ranges could be obtained from NRPE or NSCLient++ itself.

Obvious now!

Thanks for the input/ lack of input. Help's to figure out for self sometimes

Answer (score 0):

a very generic answer:

you'll have to tune your monitoring over time. especially if you dont monitor the final output [eg response time of your web app on which you have some SLA].

i suggest you start gathering some baselines, plotting charts to establish what's the general healthy level of measured parameter and how does it look when things go wrong. and based on this start setting warning levels.

Comment: OK, but my question is how do I technically go about setting up thresholds for NSClient++ external scripts?
E.g my .ps1 external script is doing exactly what I ask.. checking whether a specific process has initiated. But I do not know where to define the threshold metrics.
Any advise appreciated. Thank you